# How do I read a file as the default user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, user-input

How do I read a whole file in python 3.6.x using the user `input()` function? Like the algorithms challenge sites do. For example:

- I have a file with the following content:

  ```
  line 1
  line 2
  line 3
  end
  ```
- My program would do something like:

  ```
  x = input()
  while x != 'end':
      print("I am at", x)
      x = input()
  ```
- Then I would have as output:

  ```
  I am at line 1
  I am at line 2
  I am at line 3
  ```

I guess I need to wrap my python sample progam with another program (possible also python, or OS script) that call the first one passing the file as user input. But how could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually such challenges will pipe the input via stdin, and expected the response via stdout.

To do that, run your command from a command line like so;

```
python program.py < input.txt
```

If you want to save the output of the script into a file, you can redirect it to one.

```
python program.py < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shadow! I wish I could put you and @wim answers as correct. But I can't do it and he was faster. HAHAHA... My best!

Comment: Technically I was 3 minutes faster (mouse over the 'answered 1 hour ago' to see the timestamp :P But I don't mind either way.

Comment: Ops! You're right. To keep things fair I have set your answer as correct. Sorry for the mess, guys.

Answer (score 2):

The usual standard lib tool for this job is the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(f'working with line {line}')
```

Then from the shell, take your pick of the following (they all work):

```
$ python3 my_script.py my_file.txt
$ python3 my_script.py < my_file.txt
$ cat my_file.txt | python3 my_script.py
```